# Custom JDBCUserStoreManager unable to create jar

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create Custom JDBCUserStoreManager by following the official documentation.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager

I cant find proper steps in the documentation. Documentation link

Errors which i am getting while deploy jar in wso2 dropins

1. com.wso2.custom.hvx_userstore.App cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.3Type class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
2. com.wso2.custom.hvx_userstore.App cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.3Type class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Is there any better documentation for custom JDBCUserStoreManager creation

Need Help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog [post](https://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html). Read the comments as well since there are some discussions going on that will help you to troubleshoot and find missing resources.

You can download the sample discussed in the blog post [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/pushpalanka/SampleCustomeUserStoreManager.zip).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](http://isurad.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html) to write a new custom user store manager.